# Unable to grab a text from soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML as follows:

```
<table class="stocksTable" summary="株価詳細">
<tr>
<th class="symbol"><h1>(株)みずほフィナンシャルグループ</h1></th>
<td class="stoksPrice realTimChange">
<div class="realTimChangeMod">
</div>
</td>
td class="stoksPrice">191.1</td>
<td class="change"><span class="yjSt">前日比</span><span class="icoUpGreen yjMSt">+2.5（+1.33%）</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I tried to extract `191.1` from a line containing `td class="stoksPrice">191.1</td>`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
res = soup.find_all('stoksPrice')
print (res)
```

But result is `[]`.
How to find it guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using findAll.

Because all the previous `stoksPrice` are empty the only one that remains is the one with the price..

You can put in a check using try/except clause to check if it is a floating point number.

If it is not it will continue iterating and if it is it will return it.

```
res = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "stoksPrice"})
for r in res:
    try:
        t = float(r.text)
        print(t)
    except:
        pass
```

`191.1`

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be two issues:

First is that your usage of `find_all` is invalid. The current way you're searching for a tagname called `stoksPrice` which is wrong ad your tags are `table`, `tr`, `td`, `div`, `span`. You need to change that to:

```
>>> res = soup.find_all(class_='stoksPrice')
```

to search for tags with that class.

Second, your HTML is malformed. The list with `stoksPrice` is:

```
</td>
td class="stoksPrice">191.1</td>
```

it should have been:

```
</td>
<td class)="stoksPrice">191.1</td>
```

(Note that `<` before the `td`)
Not sure if that was a copy error into Stack Overflow or the HTML is originally malformed but that is not going to be easy to parse ...

Comment: ok. `soup.find_all(class_='stoksPrice')` prints `[<td class="stoksPrice realTimChange">
<div class="realTimChangeMod">
</div>
</td>, <td class="stoksPrice">191.1</td>]`

Comment: but i need `191.1` only, is there other methods in bs or should i do list comprehensive?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include chacks for floats

Answer (score 2):

Since there are multiple tags having the same class, you can use CSS selectors to get an exact match.

```
html = '''<table class="stocksTable" summary="株価詳細">
<tr>
<th class="symbol"><h1>(株)みずほフィナンシャルグループ</h1></th>
<td class="stoksPrice realTimChange">
<div class="realTimChangeMod">
</div>
</td>
<td class="stoksPrice">191.1</td>
<td class="change"><span class="yjSt">前日比</span><span class="icoUpGreen yjMSt">+2.5（+1.33%）</span></td>
</tr>
</table>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('td[class="stoksPrice"]').text)
# 191.1
```

Or, you could use `lambda` and `find` to get the same.

```
print(soup.find(lambda t: t.name == 'td' and t['class'] == ['stoksPrice']).text)
# 191.1
```

**Note:** BeautifulSoup converts multi-valued class attributes in lists. So, the classes of the two `td` tags look like `['stoksPrice']` and `['stoksPrice', 'realTimChange']`.